# .val returns a different value for IE than Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

For a project, I'm working with a database. Users should be able to create an entry but before they can create/edit an entry certain things have to be checked.

What I want is to check whether an input field of a form is empty, or contains 9 characters. I did this with the following code:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
    var formData = new FormData($('#ref')[0]);

    if ($("#ihcnummer").val() != '' && $("#ihcnummer").attr('value').length != 9) {
        $('#alert').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> IFS projectnumber should either be left blank, or be equal to the 9 character standard!').slideDown(10);
        $("#ihcnummer").css('border', '1px solid red');
        return;
    }
});
```

It concerns the following field:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="ihcnummer"          id="ihcnummer" value="" class="form-control"  placeholder="e.g. SP1234567">
</td>
```

This works in Chrome, but for some reason (that I do not see/understand) this doesn't work in IE. If I enter e.g. `SP1234567`, Chrome will accept this and update the database, but IE shows me the alert and will not update the database. 
If I try a different value for this field, e.g. `SP1234` It will return the warning as it should.

I have tried the `.val()`, and also the `.attr('value')`.

Why is there a difference between IE and Chrome? And how do I make sure this works on both browsers?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: try using plain js document.getElementById("ihcnummer").value

Answer (score 0):

The problem area is the usage of `.attr('value')`, As you are getting the `value` attribute it will always fetch the empty string which you have set as `''`

*Use*

```
$("#ihcnummer").val().length
```

instead of

```
$("#ihcnummer").attr('value').length
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
However, the solution you now suggest is what I used at first.
Do you have another idea?